# Create a Hadoop Cluster connection in Talend without open the IDE

Tags: talend, brooklyn

I am trying to create a "one click solution" with a Hadoop cluster, Ambari Server and a Talend via Apache Brooklyn in the cloud.

I can create all of the things, but now I have to connect them.

I am able to create "the project/connection" between the Ambari Server and the Talend manually. I have the url of the Ambari Server, so I can open the Talend and create the connection with the Hadoop cluster using the wizard of the Talend.

The question is, is there any way to do it without opening the Talend. I mean, creating manually the files that are needed and leave them into the corresponding folders.

In case of yes, which would be the files I need to create and what would be the content of this files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Talend but a few Google searches, as well as [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600897/can-i-get-access-to-talend-via-rest-api) suggest that Talend Open Studio does not come with a REST API.

As for a configuration file, I could not find any results. So my conclusion is that **it is not possible to automatised**.

When you think about it, it actually makes sense as the Talend Open Studio is mean to be a graphical and visualisation tool to build complex jobs.